# Route matching with /*path does not work as expected

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have the following router.ex:

```
scope "/api", MyAppWeb do
  get "/activate", SubscriptionController, :create, as: :activate_account
end

scope "/", MyAppWeb do
  get "/*path", AppController, :index
end
```

SubscriptionController.create/2:

```
def create(conn, %{"token" => token}) do
  ...
end
```

Doing `mix phx.routes` shows:

```
activate_account_path    GET   /api/activate   MyAppWeb.SubscriptionController :create
app_path                 GET   /*path          MyAppWeb.AppController :index
```

So, based on what that shows, in addition to the fact that the `/activate` route comes first in `router.ex`, it should be matched first.

However, when I sent a GET request to `/api/activate`, it is processed by `AppController.index/2`:

```
[info] GET /api/activate
[debug] Processing with MyAppWeb.AppController.index/2
Parameters: %{"path" => ["api", "activate"], "token" => "test"}
```

Why is it behaving this way?

P.S. I need the `/*path` catch-all for my SPA to work correctly, so removing it is not an option.

UPDATE: This turned out to be my fault. I had another `/*path` route defined earlier in router.ex that was matching. Once I removed that, and left just the one at the bottom, routes started matching correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be my fault. I had another `/*path` route defined earlier in router.ex that was matching. Once I removed that, and left just the one at the bottom, routes started matching correctly.